# Defining joint bounds for moveit

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to use getActiveJointModelsBounds() from Moveit. I am assuming Moveit get the bound values from some urdf/xacro files. If I create a new robot model and define its joint using urdf, can Moveit automatically detect the upper bound and lower bound just by reading the urdf file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328657/defining-joint-bounds-for-moveit/) by [Kolohe113](https://answers.ros.org/users/36311/kolohe113/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2019-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> If I create a new robot model and define its joint using urdf, can Moveit automatically detect the upper bound and lower bound just by reading the urdf file?

yes.

In normal MoveIt configuration packages the `planning_context.launch` file will also load a `joint_limits.yaml` file from the `config` directory which allows you / your users to override those limits ([here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/b853c6bc48c41af7475db8cbb4d11078bb8725eb/moveit_setup_assistant/templates/moveit_config_pkg_template/launch/planning_context.launch#L14-L17)).

So if `has_position_limits` is `true` in that file, the position limit from the urdf will not be used (or: will be overridden by the value in that `.yaml` file).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3